# vue-highcharts dynamic master detail chart example

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I need to implement a **master-detail** chart pair in my new site using Vue. This component  consists of two master-detail charts that are linked insofar as a selection in one makes the same selection in the other.

My requirement makes this slightly more complex than the usual examples and so it would be good to have a rudimentary but *official* master-detail example to work from such as what exists in the sample docs:

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail

I see similar has been requested before in following thread at the HighCharts forum (and maybe I misinterpret) but the ultimate example provided is conceded to not be '"good practice" code'.

https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40436

I am going to continue with the example within to try and get something up and running but wondering if anything exists out there (using the official wrapper) that the good people at HighCharts are happy to stand over as a best practise Vue implementation of this chart type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion it to implement it as a new component called for example `MasterDetailChart`, which would take the data as the `prop` and generate both charts basing on given data.
I prepared the new demo using Codesandbox platform, so please take a look on it.

Currently you can use that component, and one thing you need to do is just pass the data through component props.

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-jnqr6

Kind regards!

Comment: Thank you again @daniel_s. This has been a great help and got me to a solution!